# How to generate Jpanel to random sequence?

Tags: random, netbeans, jpanel

I am a beginner on java. I need help on how to make the codes to make the sequence of JPanels to be **random**.
I have 10 Jpanels named as P1, P2, P3 to P10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proceed in small steps.

1. Write the code to display one JPanel with fixed values.  Test this code and get it working correctly.
2. Amend the code from 1. to use random values instead of fixed values. Test this code and get it working correctly.
3. Amend the code from 2. to display more than one JPanel with random values. Test this code and get it working correctly.

Well done, you have written your program.

Comment: I'm lost, How to do the step 2 and 3 thank you. I would like to ask if you can provide an example, please bare with me and I'm sorry to bother you.

Comment: You say you are a beginner.  You will stay a beginner if I do the work for you.  To move from step 1 to step 2 you will need some random numbers.  Have a look at how to use the `java.util.Random` class.  It is covered in the Java documentation and there are many tutorials.answers on the internet, including this site.